# How do I get the Layers tab to show in the Properties menu?

Tags: interface

In other posts where people have asked this, the answer was that you needed to switch out of local view into global view for the Layers tab to appear. However, even when I was in Global View, the Layers tab was still not there. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: what layer tab are you talking about (for that matter what is the "Properties menu")? A screen shot would be very helpful here.

Comment: @David I'm talking about [this](https://imgur.com/a/jpboF) Layers Tab.

Comment: I think the layers tab that you heard disappears in local view is the scene layers that is shown in the 3D view header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you added in the comments is from an old version of blender. Since 2.67 the render layers have their own tab in the properties.

[image: render layers settings]